# When does $e^{f(x)}$ have an antiderivative?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

today I tried to integrate $x^x$ by applying a reverse chain rule which turned out to be false. I was told $\int e^{f(x)}\,dx$ can be done when $f(x)$ is linear. This made me wonder what conditions we can find so that $\int e^{f(x)}\,dx$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Integrability and "having a simple expression" are two different things. Just because you cannot find a simple expression does not mean that the function is not integrable.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Note for example that every continuous function has an antiderivative, whether it has the form $e^f$ or not.  Do you mean you want to know for which elementary functions $f$ does $e^f$ have an elementary antiderivative, in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral.

Comment: I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $f$ is a polynomial, it is a consequence of a celebrated theorem by Liouville that $e^{f(x)}$ has an elementary antiderivative iff there is a polynomial $h$ such that $1=h'+hf$. This implies that $f$ has degree at most 1. In particular, the function $e^{x^2}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative.

See [How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral).

Comment: Thanks, can anything be said when $f$ is neither a polynomial nor a log?

Comment: @Littlemisssunshine, yes, Liouville's theorem gives you the precise conditions.

Comment: + and thank you for noting me that.