# Easy method to check integrability as elementary functions

Tags: integration

What could be an easy method (Calc 1) to check if a given integral is not integrably in terms of elementary functions?

Take for example:

$$
\int e^{-t^{2}}dt$$

Comment: This definite integral has an elementary closed form: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral.

Comment: Whoops, I meant the indefinite integral. Fixed.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/404427/589 and also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028569/are-there-ways-of-telling-whether-or-not-an-integral-will-have-a-closed-expressi and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral.

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one. Calc 1 doesn't come anywhere close to proving that some functions, like $e^{-x^{2}}$, don't have elementary integrals.